# Scanf_s error with array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I have a problem with my code. Practically when the compiler performs the following line

```
scanf_s("%c", macchina[i].marca, 50);
```

Visual studio gets me this error. It gives me the same problem with the function get_s.

[image]

I cannot understand what is wrong with the code. Thanks for your support

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    struct automobile{
        char *marca;
        int modello;
        int vendute;
    };

    struct automobile macchina[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Inserisci marca: ");
        scanf_s("%c", macchina[i].marca, 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is, you did not allocate memory to `macchina[i].marca`.

Being an unitialized pointer, currently it points to some random memory location which may not be accessible from your application. Thus, the location is pretty much *invalid*.

Accessing invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To solve: either

1. Define `marca` to be an array, like `char marca[50];` or likewise
2. Allocate dynamic memory using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family before using that.

That said, you should change the format specifier to `%s` to scan a *string*. Without a width specifier, `%c` takes only a single `char`.

Comment: Of note, the `scanf` format string is also wrong; `%c` -> `%s`.

Comment: I noticed it, but I had put it just to try it, then I forgot to go back (not working anyway even with% s)

Comment: so I have to allocate memory on **marca**?

Answer (score 0):

`macchina[i].marca` is an unitialized pointer. You can't read into it without allocating memory.

Since you want to read `50` chars into it, you probably need to use `%s` (C-string) and change the definition of the struct to:

```
  struct automobile{
        char marca[50];
        int modello;
        int vendute;
    };
```

and call `scan_f()` as:

```
    scanf_s("%s", macchina[i].marca, sizeof(macchina[i].marca) );
```

If you want to the size to be dynamic, you need to use `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
macchina[i].marca
```

Is an uninitialised `char` pointer. You need to allocate memory to point it to, or you could use array.

E.g. to use an array able to hold 50 chars for this, change your code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    struct automobile{
        char marca[51];  // 50 chars + '\0' terminator
        int modello;
        int vendute;
    };

    struct automobile macchina[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Inserisci marca: ");
        scanf_s("%s", macchina[i].marca, 50); // %c is only for reading single char values, use %s for strings.
    }
}
```